# Does apache cache .htaccess rules? redirections exist even after I delete the file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I had a .htaccess file that removed all the .php extensions from the files, so if I go to localhost/path/to/file it redirects to localhost/path/to/file.php Everything worked just fine untill I decided to add a new rule to the .htaccess and it wasn't working.

I deleted the .htaccess file in my home folder and checked if some exist in other folders with the command: cd /var/www and then ls -laR | grep .htaccess and I found none existed. However the redirection rules are still being followed!

I tried to clear all of my browser's cache and still didn't work, i tried cURL and still apache followed the original rule of removing .php extensions of the files. I downloaded httpfox extension to firefox and it showed me the request I made to localhost/projectname/index and the "Content-Location" is "index.php". I tried endlessly to restart apache and with no luck.

How can I get rid of the "cached" htaccess rules?

EDIT: I tried on my iPad and my mobile device and still the problem persist, so I am sure the rules are being saved somewhere

EDIT: I added a rule to remove .html as well and it worked, but when I erased it the rule is still there and the .php one as well.

Comment: Is it possibly in some global apache configuration at ``/etc/httpd/conf.d`` or similar places?

Comment: @JonasWielicki `/etc/httpd/conf.d` does not exist, however `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is empty

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache. 301 Redirects are cached quite aggressively by browsers. Apache doesn't cache htaccess (by default).

Comment: @Gerben It sounds quite suspicious that even curl does see the redirect though…

Comment: options Multiviews could also associate missing extensions, and 301 redirections are cached in the browser (needs a restart). Also did you restart apache?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .htaccess before you deleted it?

Answer (score 4):

No, .htaccess files are not cached, by default or otherwise. (ie, there's no way to get Apache to cache .htaccess files.) They are re-read on every single request.

However, there's other places where a redirect will be cached, including your browser and any intermediate proxies between your browser and the server.

And, no, you don't need to restart Apache in order for .htaccess file changes to be seen.

Comment: You cache .htaccess by combining AllowOverride None for the directory containing the file, followed by Include /…/.htaccess. It is then only read once, on start/graceful.