# Does apache cache Rewrite Rules in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Referring to this: [Does apache cache .htaccess rules? redirections exist even after I delete the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241564/does-apache-cache-htaccess-rules-redirections-exist-even-after-i-delete-the-fi)

I was going to add a comment there but or some reason I could not.

I have this same problem. When I change a rewrite rule in my .htaccess, the old one still applies - oddly enough for one file that had been there when the rule was placed, but not any that were added later.

When I delete the .htaccess file, everything gets reset (i.e. Indexes get disabled as per the global setting). 
When I add the same .htaccess file again, then it's not applied properly. Indexes are reinstated, but the Rewrite Rules are STILL wrong.

I also notice that some odd rewrite rules seem to be in place that I **did not add**, for example my file "colors_none.css" gets redirected to "colors_note.css".

I am in a **hosted environment** and have no way to access httpd-conf or restart apache.

Is there any way to flush those settings?

Browser cache is not the problem. The same faulty behaviour occurs when I call my page from a different machine, different browser that has not called this page before.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .htaccess that you are removing/adding?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was quite some time ago :) - in the meantime I've found other workarounds for the problem I had back then. I only remember that it concerned rewrite rules that did not change behaviour after I changed them in the file.

Comment: Well if you ever remember the solution, post it as an answer to your question and you might be able to help someone else.

Comment: Well, I had no solution for this problem. I ended up rewriting the entire app and no longer needing this particular setting, so did not care whether or not it got updated properly. Sorry I can't be of more help!